# SQL query for the latest grade of employees which each employee have several records having same id

Tags: mysql, sql-server

How to find the latest grade of an employee has the same id.
my table is like:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| ID |  NAME | GRADE | 
| 1  |  ANN  |  A0   | 
| 1  |  ANN  |  A3   |  
| 2  |  JOE  |  B1   | 
| 3  | KIM   |  B3   | 
| 2  | JOE   |  B2   | 
| 3  | KIM   |  C1   | 
| 3  | KIM   |  C3   | 
+----+-------+-------+
```

How to find the latest grade of ann, Kim, and joe

my output is like:

```
name latestgrade
ann  A3
joe  B2
kim  C3
```

Comment: What is the latest grade?What is your expected output?

Comment: `mysql` <> `sql-server`

Comment: Duplicated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group

Comment: Still not clear about the database

Answer (score 0):

try row_number

```
;with cte 
as
(
 SELECT
   SeqNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY 
SUBSTRING(GRADE,1,1) desc,CAST(SUBSTRING(GRADE,2,LEN(GRADE)) AS INT) DESC),
       *
       FROM YourTable
    )
    SELECT
    * 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE SeqNo = 1
```

If you wish to insert the above result into a new table, just write a insert into before the select

```
;with cte 
    as
    (
     SELECT
       SeqNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY 
    SUBSTRING(GRADE,1,1) desc,CAST(SUBSTRING(GRADE,2,LEN(GRADE)) AS INT) DESC),
           *
           FROM YourTable
        )
insert into MyNewTable
        SELECT
        * 
        FROM CTE
        WHERE SeqNo = 1
```

Comment: If `A10` & `A9` are there as `Grade` values, your code will select `A9`. Hope it should select `A10`.

Comment: it should select A10

Comment: @AnuAntony : Which rdbms are you using? [Check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47747295/sql-query-for-the-latest-grade-of-employees-which-each-employee-have-several-rec#47747358)

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh : Still it's not correct dude. Now `A9` and `B9` then?

Comment: It work's for me @Wanderer. check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/415fe/1

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh then it should select B9

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh :`B1` and `A10`, it should select `B1`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8a281/1

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh i want the output as a new table

Comment: @AnuAntony cte acts as a virtual table and if you want those records to a new table, then you can directly insert those records to your new table from cte

Comment: now you can write a insert into just before the select * from cte and insert the results to your table

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh  yeah created a new table which has employee id and latest grade as the fields. but I have another question when the latest grade of ann is changed A3 To B1. THEN HOW TO AUTOMATICALLY UPDATE THE NEW TABLE?

Comment: You will have to write a trigger to update based on the above Query

Answer (score 0):

Give a row number group by ID and order by the descending order of Grade

**Sql Server Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        partition by [ID]
        order by len([GRADE]) desc, [GRADE] desc
    ), *
    from [your_table_name]
)
select [ID], [NAME], [GRADE]
from cte
where [rn] = 1;
```

**[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b5b5f/1)**

**MySql Query**

```
select t1.`ID`, t1.`NAMME`, t1.`GRADE` from (
    select `ID`, `NAME`, `GRADE`, (
        case `ID` when @curA 
        then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        else @curRow := 1 and @curA := `ID` end 
    ) as `rn` 
    from `your_table_name` t, 
    (select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r 
    order by `ID`, length(`GRADE`) desc, `GRADE` desc
)t1 
where t1.`rn` = 1;
```

**[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5b5f5/1)**